# Migrating reverse proxy settings from Nginx to Apache2

Tags: nginx, apache2

until now I have been using Nginx but due to some reasons I have to switch to Apache2. I am not a sys admin so if more info is needed, just ask

I am unable to migrate 1 simple proxy settings to Apache2:

```
location /auth {
  proxy_pass http://localhost;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Especially how to migrate header `X-Forwarded-For`, because I do not know what could be the equivalent in Apache2

Comment: why would you go away from nginx?

Comment: thats not up to me but on other people around me. I can not do anything with it.

Comment: `X-Forwarded-For` is added automatically by Apache `mod_proxy`.